# parsing xml data return empty in php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to read below xml from PHP and return empty. What I'm doing wrong?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<page>
  <settings>
    <ss_pageRef><![CDATA[1]]></ss_pageRef>
    <ss_pageType><![CDATA[juicebox]]></ss_pageType>
    <ss_navName><![CDATA[Gallery]]></ss_navName>
    <ss_navWeight><![CDATA[1]]></ss_navWeight>
    <ss_navShow><![CDATA[true]]></ss_navShow>
    <ss_indexShow><![CDATA[true]]></ss_indexShow>
    <ss_parentPage><![CDATA[0]]></ss_parentPage>
    <ss_pageTitle><![CDATA[New gallery page]]></ss_pageTitle>
    <ss_pageDescription><![CDATA[This is gallery one]]></ss_pageDescription>
    <ss_pageBody><![CDATA[<p>Enter page body text here.</p>]]></ss_pageBody>
    <galleryTitle><![CDATA[]]></galleryTitle>
  </settings>
</page>
```

PHP

```
$galleries = simplexml_load_file("../gallery/page.xml") or die ("no gallery found");

print_r($galleries);

echo $galleries->ss_pageDescription;
```

Print_r

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [settings] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ss_pageRef] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_pageType] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_navName] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_navWeight] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_navShow] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_indexShow] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_parentPage] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_pageTitle] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_pageDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ss_pageBody] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [galleryTitle] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not echo'ing anything is because `<ss_PageDescription />` is nested within `<settings />`.

```
echo $galleries->settings->ss_pageDescription;
```